# Convert/export Xcode project to Playground file (.playground)

Tags: xcode

I am building a game using SpriteKit in Xcode and I am also trying to export/save Xcode project to Playground file (.playground file type) but it was not successful. I have tried to Google various pages and different ways, but it also did not work. Is there any solution for it?

Besides, within Playground project, can I create Scene file (.sks file type) to put image files on it as nodes? or it can only create the swift file?

Thanks all